# Facebook Messenger Broadcast API Targetting with Multiple Labels Possible?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Question about the Broadcast API.

I am reading Facebook's "Targeting Broadcast Messages (beta)" documentation, and it seems that I cannot set more than one label during broadcast, can I?

So if create different labels for "teenagers", "male", "in Melbourne", I cannot run a broadcast API to "male teenagers in Melbourrne" with just one label?

If that is not possible, does it mean to achieve what I want, I need to get all my subscribers' PSID (ex. 10000 of them) and then associate a new label (meaning, i will make 10000 requests to Facebook's API) and then send a Broadcast Message? (I somehow think I will get blocked for spamming)

Comment: How did you create a label that groups male teenagers in Melbourne? I guess there should be such a feature somewhere inside Bot Page settings but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would create one label that represents 'male teenagers in melbourne', associate that to all applicable PSIDs, then target that label with your broadcast. You won't get blocked for spamming just for sending the broadcast. Sending a message to a large number of users is exactly what the Broadcast API is for.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I will do. I was more concerned with labelling 10000 users to associate them with a Broadcast Label. That would send 10000 requests to Facebook Graph API.

I found a link to Facebook GRAPH API with a section about rate limiting, and the limit of requests to the API, and it seems I can send a LOT of requests... It is pretty sweet. I shouldn't be worried.